# Parse error in variable parsing PHP

Tags: php

Below is the code that I am currently using:

```
  $form = "
  <form action='echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Username</td>
  </td><input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>";

  ?>
```

The above code is giving me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ... on line 27
```

If I change this: `["PHP_SELF"]` to this `['PHP_SELF']`, then I recieve this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ... on line 27
```

How can I fix the form action above so that it stops returning with parse errors?

Comment: You're closing your string unexpectedly. `"...$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]..."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
<form action='echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);' method='post'>
```

to

```
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
```

You're already in PHP and building a string so there's no need for the echo within the string.

Answer (score 6):

Change it from:

```
<form action='echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);' method='post'>
```

to:

```
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
```

You're building your HTML using a double-quoted string; so when PHP sees the double quotes delimiting `"PHP_SELF"`, it's assuming that the first one terminates your string. It then tries to parse `PHP_SELF`, and can't do so.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on strings for further reference.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but providing an explanation is more useful than just providing the "code".  If the initial cause is not understood, then an answer is meaningless.

Comment: @RobB - thank you; I'll add some text.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `$form` variable and place the HTML code outside the closing PHP bracket:

```
<?php
//php code

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
</td><input type='text' name='user' value='<?php echo $getuser; ?>' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use `.` for concatenation in PHP at this line

```
<form action='echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);' method='post'>
```

You should write

```
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
```

Comment: Argh Damned ! I'm so sloooow ! :D